# Simpson diversity index

Tags: code-golf, math

The [Simpson index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index#Simpson_index) is a measure of diversity of a collection of items with duplicates. It is simply the probability of drawing two different items when picking without replacement uniformly at random.

With `n` items in groups of `n_1, ..., n_k` identical items, the probability of two different items is

[image: $$1-\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{n_i(n_i-1)}{n(n -1)}$$]

For example, if you have 3 apples, 2 bananas, and 1 carrot, the diversity index is

`D = 1 - (6 + 2 + 0)/30 = 0.7333`

Alternatively, the number of unordered pairs of different items is `3*2 + 3*1 + 2*1 = 11` out of 15 pairs overall, and `11/15 = 0.7333`.

**Input:**

A string of characters `A` to `Z`. Or, a list of such characters. Its length will be at least 2. You may not assume it to be sorted.

**Output:**

The Simpson diversity index of characters in that string, i.e., the probability that two characters taken randomly with replacement are different. This is a number between 0 and 1 inclusive.

When outputting a float, display at least 4 digits, though terminating exact outputs like `1` or `1.0` or `0.375` are OK.

You may not use built-ins that specifically compute diversity indices or entropy measures. Actual random sampling is fine, as long as you get sufficient accuracy on the test cases.

**Test cases**

```
AAABBC 0.73333
ACBABA 0.73333
WWW 0.0
CODE 1.0
PROGRAMMING 0.94545
```

**Leaderboard**

Here's a by-language leaderboard, courtesy of [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner).

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

```js
function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/53455/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function getAnswers(){$.ajax({url:answersUrl(page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:true,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items);if(e.has_more)getAnswers();else process()}})}function shouldHaveHeading(e){var t=false;var n=e.body_markdown.split("\n");try{t|=/^#/.test(e.body_markdown);t|=["-","="].indexOf(n[1][0])>-1;t&=LANGUAGE_REG.test(e.body_markdown)}catch(r){}return t}function shouldHaveScore(e){var t=false;try{t|=SIZE_REG.test(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0])}catch(n){}return t}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){answers=answers.filter(shouldHaveScore).filter(shouldHaveHeading);answers.sort(function(e,t){var n=+(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[Infinity])[0],r=+(t.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[Infinity])[0];return n-r});var e={};var t=1;answers.forEach(function(n){var r=n.body_markdown.split("\n")[0];var i=$("#answer-template").html();var s=r.match(NUMBER_REG)[0];var o=(r.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0];var u=r.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1];var a=getAuthorName(n);i=i.replace("{{PLACE}}",t++ +".").replace("{{NAME}}",a).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",u).replace("{{SIZE}}",o).replace("{{LINK}}",n.share_link);i=$(i);$("#answers").append(i);e[u]=e[u]||{lang:u,user:a,size:o,link:n.share_link}});var n=[];for(var r in e)if(e.hasOwnProperty(r))n.push(e[r]);n.sort(function(e,t){if(e.lang>t.lang)return 1;if(e.lang<t.lang)return-1;return 0});for(var i=0;i<n.length;++i){var s=$("#language-template").html();var r=n[i];s=s.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",r.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",r.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",r.size).replace("{{LINK}}",r.link);s=$(s);$("#languages").append(s)}}var QUESTION_ID=45497;var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";var answers=[],page=1;getAnswers();var SIZE_REG=/\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;[^&]*&lt;\/s&gt;|[^&]+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/;var NUMBER_REG=/\d+/;var LANGUAGE_REG=/^#*\s*((?:[^,\s]|\s+[^-,\s])*)/
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js></script><link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id=answer-list><h2>Leaderboard</h2><table class=answer-list><thead><tr><td></td><td>Author<td>Language<td>Size<tbody id=answers></table></div><div id=language-list><h2>Winners by Language</h2><table class=language-list><thead><tr><td>Language<td>User<td>Score<tbody id=languages></table></div><table style=display:none><tbody id=answer-template><tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}<td>{{LANGUAGE}}<td>{{SIZE}}<td><a href={{LINK}}>Link</a></table><table style=display:none><tbody id=language-template><tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}<td>{{NAME}}<td>{{SIZE}}<td><a href={{LINK}}>Link</a></table>
```

Comment: You're using the Gini-Simpson index, when a much better measure to use is the inverse Simpson index a.k.a. effective number of types.

Comment: Basically `1/` instead of `1-`. [amateur statistician rant hat off]

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 72

The input may be a string or a list.

```
def f(s):l=len(s);return sum(s[i%l]<>s[i/l]for i in range(l*l))/(l-1.)/l
```

I already know that it would be 2 bytes shorter in Python 3 so please don't advise me :)

Comment: What are the angle brackets `<>` doing at position 36? I've never seen that syntax before.

Comment: @TuttiFruttiJacuzzi: it's a synonym for `!=`.

Comment: @TuttiFruttiJacuzzi It's only python 2 unless you [`from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0401/)

Comment: @Vioz- Not with the `l=len(s);` in there

Comment: @Sp3000 Right, didn't notice how many times it was used.

Answer (score 5):

## J, 26 bytes

```
1-+/((#&:>@</.~)%&(<:*])#)
```

### the cool part

I found the counts of each character by keying `</.` the string against itself (`~` for reflexive) then counting the letters of each box.

Comment: `(#&:>@</.~)` can be `(#/.~)` and `(<:*])` can be `(*<:)`. If you use a proper function this gives `(1-(#/.~)+/@:%&(*<:)#)`. As the surrounding braces are generally not counted here (leaving `1-(#/.~)+/@:%&(*<:)#`, the body of the function) this gives 20 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - <strike>19</strike> <strike>13</strike> <strike>12</strike> 11 bytes

*Thanks to @isaacg for telling me about n*

Uses brute force approach with `.c` combinations function.

```
csnMK.cz2lK
```

[Try it here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=csnMK.cz2lK&input=AAABBC&debug=1).

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V.zcsnMK.cN2lK&input=AAABBC%0AACBABA%0AWWW%0ACODE%0APROGRAMMING&debug=1).

```
c                Float division
 s               Sum (works with True and False)
  nM             Map uniqueness
   K             Assign value to K and use value
    .c 2         Combinations of length 2
      z          Of input
 lK              Length of K
```

Comment: You can replace `.{` with `n`- they're equivalent here.

Comment: @isaacg oh didn't know it automatically splats, cool.

Answer (score 4):

## SQL (PostgreSQL), 182 Bytes

As a function in postgres.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION F(TEXT)RETURNS NUMERIC AS'SELECT 1-sum(d*(d-1))/(sum(d)*(sum(d)-1))FROM(SELECT COUNT(*)d FROM(SELECT*FROM regexp_split_to_table($1,''''))I(S)GROUP BY S)A'LANGUAGE SQL
```

Explanation

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION F(TEXT) -- Create function f taking text parameter
RETURNS NUMERIC         -- declare return type
AS'                     -- return definition
    SELECT 1-sum(d*(d-1))/(sum(d)*(sum(d)-1)) -- Calculate simpson index
    FROM(
        SELECT COUNT(*)d  -- Count occurrences of each character
        FROM(             -- Split the string into characters
            SELECT*FROM regexp_split_to_table($1,'''')
            )I(S)
        GROUP BY S        -- group on the characters
        )A 
'
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Usage and Test Run

```sql
SELECT S, F(S)
FROM (
    VALUES
    ('AAABBC'),
    ('ACBABA'),
    ('WWW'),
    ('CODE'),
    ('PROGRAMMING')
   )I(S)

S              F
-------------- -----------------------
AAABBC         0.73333333333333333333
ACBABA         0.73333333333333333333
WWW            0.00000000000000000000
CODE           1.00000000000000000000
PROGRAMMING    0.94545454545454545455
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>66</s> 58 Bytes

This is using the simple counting formula provided in the question, nothing too complicated. It's an anonymous lambda function, so to use it, you need to give it a name.

*Saved 8 bytes(!) thanks to Sp3000.*

```py
lambda s:1-sum(x-1for x in map(s.count,s))/len(s)/~-len(s)
```

Usage:

```py
>>> f=lambda s:1-sum(x-1for x in map(s.count,s))/len(s)/~-len(s)
>>> f("PROGRAMMING")
0.945454
```

or

```py
>>> (lambda s:1-sum(x-1for x in map(s.count,s))/len(s)/~-len(s))("PROGRAMMING")
0.945454
```

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 119 bytes

Today on "Komali sucks at code golf"...

```js
s=>eval('q=[];for(i of new Set(s))q.push((r=s.split(i).length-1)*(r-1));1-(q.reduce((z,x)=>x+z)/((l=s.length)*(l-1)))')
```

Test cases:

```js
let s1= "AAABBC"
let s2 = "ACBABA"
let s3 = "WWW";
let s4 = "CODE";
let s5 = "PROGRAMMING"
let f = 
s=>eval('q=[];for(i of new Set(s))q.push((r=s.split(i).length-1)*(r-1));1-(q.reduce((z,x)=>x+z)/((l=s.length)*(l-1)))')

console.log(f(s1))
console.log(f(s2))
console.log(f(s3))
console.log(f(s4))
console.log(f(s5))
```

Came across this question while doing biology homework. There has to be ways to improve this; I only spent like half an hour golfing it...

Comment: `(r-1)` ->`~-r`, ditto with `l` (you might just want a separate function that does n*n-1), `q.reduce((z,x)=>x+z)` -> eval(q.join\`+\`)` although you probably want to make `q` a number and add to it.

Answer (score 3):

## APL, <s>39</s> 36 bytes

```
{n←{≢⍵}⌸⍵⋄N←≢⍵⋄1-(N-⍨N×N)÷⍨+/n-⍨n×n}
```

This creates an unnamed monad.

```
{
  n ← {≢⍵}⌸⍵               ⍝ Number of occurrences of each letter
  N ← ≢⍵                   ⍝ Number of characters in the input
  1-(N-⍨N×N)÷⍨+/n-⍨n×n     ⍝ Return 1 - sum((n*n-n)/(N*N-N))
}
```

You can [try it online](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7Bn%u2190%7B%u2262%u2375%7D%u2338%u2375%u22C4N%u2190%u2262%u2375%u22C41-+/%28%28n-%u2368n%D7n%29%F7%28N-%u2368N%D7N%29%29%7D%27PROGRAMMING%27&run)!

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, 56

```python
lambda s:sum(a!=b for a in s for b in s)/len(s)/~-len(s)
```

Counts the pairs of unequal elements, then divides by the number of such pairs.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
csnM*zz*lztlz
```

Pretty much a literal translation of @feersum's solution.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 25 bytes

```
l$_e`0f=_:(.*:+\,_(*d/1\-
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%24_e%600f%3D_%3A(.*%3A%2B%5C%2C_(*d%2F1%5C-&input=ACBABA)

Fairly direct implementation of the formula in the question.

Explanation:

```
l     Get input.
$     Sort it.
_     Copy for evaluation of denominator towards the end.
e`    Run-length encoding of string.
0f=   Map letter/length pairs from RLE to only length.
      We now have a list of letter counts.
_     Copy list.
:(    Map with decrement operator. Copy now contains letter counts minus 1.
.*    Vectorized multiply. Results in list of n*(n-1) for each letter.
:+    Sum vector. This is the numerator.
\     Bring copy of input string to top.
,     Calculate length.
_(    Copy and decrement.
*     Multiply. This is the denominator, n*(n-1) for the entire string.
d     Convert to double, otherwise we would get integer division.
/     Divide.
1\-   Calculate one minus result of division to get final result.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 30 bytes

```
{1-+//((x=\:x)-=l)%(l-1)*l:#x}
```

33 bytes if you want it to be faster:

```
{1-(+/j x)%(j:{x*x-1})[+/x]}@#'=:
```

This is the part where not having combinators hurt k's expressiveness. Also the problem statement is wrong: the equation corresponds to taking elements *without* replacement.

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6o21NXW19fQqLDVt4qxqtDUtc3RVNXI0TXU1MqxUq6o5UoDKdHQ1s9SqABKZFlVV2hV6BrWakZr61fE1jooq9tacXGlKSg5Ojs5OjkqgZjh4eFKXFxcAGV2FvA=)

Answer (score 2):

## **JavaScript, 105 bytes**

```
f=(r,f=[],n=0,a=0)=>{for(k in [...r].map(k=>f[k]=(f[k]||0)+ ++n/n),f)a+=f[k]*(f[k]-1);return 1-a/(n*n-n)}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I don't think you need the `f=`, so this can be two bytes shorter.

Comment: Well done; beat me! I believe you can omit the initial braces and `return` if you put the whole thing in an `eval`. Also you can probably put the definitions for `a` and `n` outside the arguments if you do `a=n=0;for(/*...*/`. Regardless, very nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 81 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.map(t=>s[t]=-~s[t])&&s.map(x=>(n++,a=s[x],s[x]=0,q+=a--*a),n=q=0)&&1-q/n--/n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBDoMgEEVvo1AYtAcYE@wxCIuJ1aaNHURI48qro6ab/15e/od@lIb1vWTg8BzLhCVhl8yXFpFPcdkj7BdkVf3zhp1gpTRhcpvX12Cro0ICuJHUjBHb832H2DBAw2UInMI8mjm8xCScMaa21vb9o/ZSlgM)

Magic

The first part defines letters as keys of `s` by abusing that the default key is undefined, and `-~undefined` = 1. Then, we iteratively delete the dictionary entries after using them (the first time we encounter them) while incrementing `n` to count the length. Finally, we compute `1-q/n--/n`.

Comment: Nice! Glad to see this golfed down...

Answer (score 1):

## J, 37 bytes

```
(1-([:+/]*<:)%+/*[:<:+/)([:+/"1~.=/])
```

but I believe it can be still shortened.

Example

```
(1-([:+/]*<:)%+/*[:<:+/)([:+/"1~.=/]) 'AAABBC'
```

This is just a tacit version of the following function:

```
   fun =: 3 : 0
a1=.+/"1 (~.y)=/y
N=.(+/a1)*(<:+/a1)
n=.a1*a1-1
1-(+/n)%N
)
```

Comment: After some extra golfing and making it a proper function: `(1-(%&([:+/]*<:)+/)@(+/"1@=))` gives 29 bytes. 27 if we don't count the braces surrounding the function `(1-(%&([:+/]*<:)+/)@(+/"1@=))` as it is common here. Notes: `=y` is exactly `(~.=/])y` and the compose conjuction (`x u&v y` = `(v x) u (v y)`) was very helpful too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I am still learning to write tacit expressions myself. For now, I use 13 : 0 to generate tacit definitions part by part and combine.

Answer (score 1):

## C,89

Score is for the function `f` only and excludes unnecessary whitespace, which is only included for clarity. the `main` function is only for testing.

```
i,c,n;
float f(char*v){
  n=strlen(v);
  for(i=n*n;i--;)c+=v[i%n]!=v[i/n]; 
  return 1.0*c/(n*n-n);
}

main(int C,char**V){
  printf("%f",f(V[1]));
}
```

It simply compares every character with every other character, then divides by the total number of comparisons.

Comment: at `return 1.0`, couldn't you golf the `0` ?

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 23 bytes

```
1r$e`{0=,~}%_:+\,,:+d/-
```

Byte-wise, this is a very minor improvement over [@RetoKoradi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53461), but it uses a neat trick:

The sum of the first **n** non-negative integers equals **n(n - 1)/2**, which we can use to calculate the numerator and denominator, both divided by **2**, of the fraction in the question's formula.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=1r%24e%60%7B0%3D%2C~%7D%25_%3A%2B%5C%2C%2C%3A%2Bd%2F-&input=PROGRAMMING).

#### How it works

```
 r$                     e# Read a token from STDIN and sort it.
   e`                   e# Perform run-length encoding.
     {    }%            e# For each [length character] pair:
      0=                e#   Retrieve the length of the run (L).
        ,~              e#   Push 0 1 2 ... L-1.
                        e# Collect all results in an array.
            _:+         e# Push the sum of the entries of a copy.
               \,       e# Push the length of the array (L).
                 ,:+    e# Push 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + L-1 = L(L-1)/2.
                    d/  e# Cast to Double and divide.
1                     - e# Subtract the result from 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 83 bytes

I know I'm late, found this, had forgotten to post. Kinda inelegant with Haskell requiring me to convert integers to numbers that you can divide by each other.

```
s z=(l(filter id p)-l z)/(l p-l z) where p=[c==d|c<-z,d<-z]
l=fromIntegral.length
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 26 bytes

```
{1-+/÷/{⍵×⍵-1}({⍴⍵}⌸⍵),≢⍵}
```

Explanation:

- `≢⍵`: get the length of the first dimension of `⍵`. Given that `⍵` is supposed to be a string, this means the length of the string.
- `{⍴⍵}⌸⍵`: for each unique element in `⍵`, get the lengths of each dimension of the list of occurrences. This gives the amount of times an item occurs for each item, as a `1×≢⍵` matrix.
- `,`: concatenate the two along the horizontal axis. Since `≢⍵` is a scalar, and the other value is a column, we get a `2×≢⍵` matrix where the first column has the amount of times an item occurs for each item, and the second column has the total amount of items.
- `{⍵×⍵-1}`: for each cell in the matrix, calculate `N(N-1)`.
- `÷/`: reduce rows by division. This divides the value for each item by the value for the total.
- `+/`: sum the result for each row.
- `1-`: subtract it from 1

Answer (score 1):

### PHP 4 (72 chars)

Given *$argv[1]* as a command line argument :

```php
foreach(count_chars($argv[1])as$c)@$r-=$c*$c+$g-$g+=$c;echo$r/$g/--$g+1;
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##PY1BC4IwFMfP7lMMeeCWing2q81COljhxUNFjGHbSWVqENFnt3mwy/@994P3@3e6m6b1ttMderamFlITYYx4E48xxnnmBR7LOOPMLlVV2czO@4Mdl/Kcl6wojqfco1j0GIRRr2t8p@iDnFrqFrsLwukGuwlylgbZjs3wkFqYnvzfRA@S7sCEKcgVSB9UCMq3RzLLwESgonBGcbL4b81sHZu@HgiYABRN0BdN0w8)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 67 bytes

```
=LET(n,COUNTA(A:A),c,COUNTIF(A:A,UNIQUE(A:A)),1-SUM(c^2-c)/(n^2-n))
```

Input is a list of characters in the column A. One character per cell. Output is wherever the formula is which can be anywhere except in column A.

The [LET()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function allows you to define variables that can be referenced later and it saves most of the bytes here. The arguments are in pairs of `variable,value` except for the last argument which is not in a pair and is instead the output.

- `n,COUNTA(A:A)` stores the count of how many non-blank cells there are in column A.
- `c,COUNTIF(A:A,UNIQUE(A:A))` creates an array of all the unique items from column A and then counts how many times each of those unique values appear. Technically, the UNIQUE() array will include a `0` at the end (presuming there are blank cells in `A:A`) but COUNTIF() will return `0` for it's count so that doesn't impact the calculations.
- `1-SUM(c^2-c)/(n^2-n)` is the final output. Except for turning `a(a-1)` into `a^2-a` to save a byte, then is a straightforward implementation of the formula. The denominator could have also been `/n/(n-1)` for the same byte count but I chose the more aesthetically pleasing option.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `=LET(n,ROWS(A1#),c,COUNTIF(A1#,UNIQUE(A1#)),1-SUM(c^2-c)/(n^2-n))` (or `=LET(a,A1#,...)` ) lets you drop two bytes if you specify that input must be of the form of a vertically aligned array of chars (ie [A1]=`={"a";"b";"a";"a";"b";"c"}`)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 75 bytes

```
seq(inString(Ans,sub(Ans,I,1)),I,1,length(Ans→A
SortA(ʟA
augment({0},1 and ΔList(ʟA
seq(sum(cumSum(Ans)=I),I,0,sum(Ans
1-sum(Ans²-Ans)/(sum(Ans)²-sum(Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans` as a string. Output is stored in `Ans` and is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 31 bytes

A port of [xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53581/9288).

```matlab
@(s)nnz(s!=s')/(l=nnz(s))/(l-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKunp/ffQaNYMy@vSqNY0bZYXVNfI8cWzNMEMXUNNf@naSg5Ojo6OTkraXKB2M5Ojk6OEHZ4eDiE4ezv4gphBQT5uwc5@vp6@rkraf4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
{1-/%/{x*x-1}(#'=x;#x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#eJx1j0FrwkAUhO/vVyyxpVpINsGE0iw9bNIiPVhFCjlIwJBsdFGzNrstG4L+9mY1FD103uUNM4dvyrD1bHyPW/2obe84HDy8aDLQoyOACtu7ZXOqwxIhpMlKbMlwVWZ8RzRpSD1KTWdpUUqjKLaI6zyNb+Sn5ziOaET/jZMkMZl7NvHs9c0iXu/mi9lkQafT94+JqTz7wc2lABg2Sh1kiHEuCrYWu9KRKsu3TOebrFozJxd7/PXNpOKikjgY+0GAJd8fpKjsgv+wWnLV2LwqmAb47HoozySTAJdRqIeGy4g/20F3vwuGF3W4cIWKelIw+gV/z15q)

An adaption of @marinus' [APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79623/98547).

- `(#'=x;#x)` create a two item list containing: a dictionary mapping each distinct character to the number of times it appears in the input; and the length of the input string
- `{x*x-1}` multiply each value in the above list by itself minus one
- `%/` divide the (adjusted) counts of characters by the (adjusted) length of the input
- `1-/` use a minus-reduce, seeded with 1, subtracting each of the above to (implicitly) return the metric

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 100 bytes

```js
a=>(n=a.length,1-[...new Set(a)].map(b=>((c=a.split(b).length-1)-1)*c).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)/(n*(n-1)))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! Glad to see the `eval` was able to be omitted with this strategy!

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 96 bytes

```js
a=>eval('h=0,c=0,o=[];for(i of a)o[i]=o[i]+1||1,c++;for(i in o)h+=(v=o[i])*(v-1);1-h/(c*(c-1))')
```

Posted this as a seperate answer since it's not an update to my older one.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 16 bytes

```
ĐĐỤ⇹ɔ⁻△Ʃ⇹Ł⁻△ᵮ/⁻~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIQjEx7uXvKofefJKY8adz@atvnYSiDnaCOE83DrOn0gq@7//2j1RHUdOE6C4mT1WAA)

Takes a list of characters

```
ĐĐ                    implicit input; Đuplicates on the stack twice
  Ụ                   get Ụnique elements
   ⇹ɔ                 get ɔount of each unique element in original list
     ⁻△               decrement count and get the corresponding triangular number n*(n-1)
       Ʃ              sum the triangular numbers
        ⇹Ł            get Łength of original list
          ⁻△          decrement and get triangular number
            ᵮ/        divide (cast to ᵮloat first due to bug in division coding)
              ⁻~      subtract one and negate (equivalent to subtracting from one)
                      implicit print
```